# Not able to get error msg generated by failWith using ConseilJS

Tags: node, ligo, conseiljs

I am trying to invoke my contract with conseiljs.TezosNodeWriter.sendContractInvocationOperation().

Everything works fine with a positive scenario but when I purposely fail the script with some error message like "not enough balance".

All I get in try-catch is :

```
Error: failed: (temporary: proto.006-PsCARTHA.michelson_v1.runtime_error), (temporary: proto.006-PsCARTHA.michelson_v1.script_rejected)
```

It just says that your script failed because it hit failwith somewhere but I want the message.
Is there any way to do it?
I was not able to find anything in the documentation.
Thanks in advance.